# Не сохраняется bitmap на телефон(android)

Tags: android

не могу сохранить bitmap на телефон. Может кто знает, что я делаю не так?

```
private void saveAsBitmap(Bitmap bm, String filename) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()+"/saved1.png");
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 75, fos);

            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyLog", e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Почему `bitmap.compress` если параметр `bm`? Может в этом проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Данного кода достаточно, чтобы сохранить битмап. Как подсказали в комментах, у вас неверно определен входной параметр метода, который нужно сохранить.

```
try (FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos); // bm - ваш Bitmap
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```